# Volume Displacement Submergence Question (Read for details)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, volume

If a person's entire body is submerged in water, and they get an erection, will the water level ultimately be higher than before or not change at all?

Comment: Welcome to PhyicsSE :) What are your thoughts to solve this question? Does archimedes principle of the gold crown help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When floating in the water you displace your mass.  When submerged you displace your volume.

If you're still floating then we know for sure nothing will change, as your mass is constant.

You only sink if you are the same density or more dense than water.  In that case your max displacement is volume.

If you get an erection there are 2 potential situations.  The first is that you actually increase your volume.  This should technically lower your density, so we assume youre still submerged though.  You would need to add enough force with your erection to displace the water.

I don't think that is realistic.  Instead, your volume wouldn't actually increase.  The increased volume down under will probably comes from blood at a different location.  Your overall volume doesn't change and therefore the water is the same.

If we assume your volume does actually change, that would require the gas in your lungs to expand or something to make the density change.  I think it's more likely your body compresses a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Why would your body's volume change? A change in volume implies a change in density (constant mass). I don't think your body changes density when you get an erection, so the water level would stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of the person's body increases. The new volume will displace some amount of water. Therefore, the water level will rise.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is an interesting question but I agree that the level of the water would not change...

However, when a person dies, certain reactions occur that change their body composition (i believe mostly it fills with gas) and their dead body can suddenly float, when it sank before.

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE :) Could you back up your thoughts with laws of Physics, please?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).